# chartjs tooltip html: Use data to populate tooltip

Tags: html, chart.js, tooltip

I an updating a 10 year website that used highcharts and I am converting it to chartjs.

In the data it had a extra field for the tooltip that was a html string.

Example:

```
data: [
{x: 0,y:395.8,extra: 'Aug 11 2020 00:56:48<br/>12% <br>395.8  <br/>53.9 <br/>56.1 Inches, 95 \u00B0F<br/>4.674 , 0 , 582 , 1000 , 00'},
{x: 1,y:390.2,extra: 'Aug 11 2020 01:56:48<br/>12% <br>390.2  <br/>53.1 <br/>56.2 Inches, 93.2 \u00B0F<br/>4.681 , 0 , 582 , 1000 , 00'},
{x: 2,y:395.8,extra: 'Aug 11 2020 02:56:49<br/>12% <br>395.8  <br/>53.9 <br/>56.1 Inches, 93.2 \u00B0F<br/>4.676 , 0 , 582 , 1000 , 00'}
}]
```

I was wonder how to do the same with chart.js.
The data is being put in from PHP database.
So I can change it from the extra field, but where would I put it?

Thanks in advance. ( new to chart.js sorry)

Comment: You have used the Highcharts tag - please be aware that chart.js and Highcharts are two different, standalone libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve what you want if you disable the default tooltip and create a custom one.

If you have access to the php API, I would personally change the data so that the date is on the x axis rather than just numbers.

```
var customTooltip = function(tooltip) {
  $(this._chart.canvas).css('cursor', 'pointer');

  var positionY = this._chart.canvas.offsetTop;
  var positionX = this._chart.canvas.offsetLeft;

  $('.chart-tooltip').css({
    opacity: 0
  });

  if (!tooltip || !tooltip.opacity) {
    return;
  }

  if (tooltip.dataPoints.length > 0) {
    tooltip.dataPoints.forEach(function(dataPoint) {
      var content = extra[dataPoint.index];

      $('#tooltip').html(content);
      $('#tooltip').css({
        opacity: 1,
        top: positionY + dataPoint.y + 'px',
        left: positionX + dataPoint.x + 'px',
      });
    });
  }
};
```

I have created a fiddle to demonstrate using your data: https://jsfiddle.net/y01ewbtz/

Comment: When I copy all the code into page It shows the chart but the tooltip is not showing like it does with jsfiddle

Comment: Can you expand on "not showing like it does with jsfiddle" please? is this a css/style issue or is the tooltip not showing at all?

Comment: It works now. Added more data and one of the extra was eztra

Comment: The datapoint.datasetIndex is not increasing so the tooltip is always the first one.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm not sure why the datasetIndex is not incrementing, anyway it can be replaced with index, please see the new [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4faLxbd3/3/)

Comment: looking at this again the reason datsetIndex is not incrementing is because you only have 1 dataset which is why it should have been index in the first place, I have updated the answer with the new fiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220056/discussion-between-lkirin-and-chris).